# Insert linebreaks into a character-variable

Tags: r, tidyverse

What's the most elegant way in R to insert linebreaks into a char-Variable?

For example I have the following data.frame:

```
longValues <- c("This is a very long text that should include linebreaks", "And also this is a very long text, that should include linereaks", "And this is an even longer text without linebreaks")
df <- data.frame(longValues)
df
```

I would like to create a new variable containing the same values as `longValues`, but a linebreak ("\n") should be inserted after a certain number of characters (lets say 20) but it should be inserted BETWEEN two words. So if the 20. character lies within a word the linebreak should come after that word.

The result should be like this:

```
df$linebreaks <- c("This is a very long\n 
                 text that should include\n
                 linebreaks", 
                "And also this is a very
                long text, that should\n 
                include linereaks", 
                "And this is an even \n
                longer text without \n
                linebreaks")
```

Comment: Can you show expected output please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stringr::str_wrap` will do the job:

```
library(stringr)
str_wrap(df$longValues, width = 20)

#> [1] "This is a very long\ntext that should\ninclude linebreaks"          
#> [2] "And also this is\na very long text,\nthat should include\nlinereaks"
#> [3] "And this is an even\nlonger text without\nlinebreaks"
```